# Posted on Facebook Java Android

Tags: java, android-studio

I am a Android app developer
I want to share a photo on facebook with some explanation like the picture I have uploaded
What I want is a card that contains a picture and a description and when I click on it, I transfer it to Google Play
[I need share on Facebook like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2CrD.jpg)

Comment: Would you please give more details concerning your question? It's very unclear.

Comment: You can take a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want

Comment: I have added more details about the topic

Comment: This is just a set of requirements. What is your actual question? What kind of answer are you hoping to get?

Comment: @Kenster I want to share a picture with text content and add a style like the picture you uploaded. What library should I use or want an example of this I have searched a lot but I did not find any topic talking about sharing a picture with text on Facebook and I have tried many code But only publishes one image or text and can not publish two with each other
What do I want to shorten it? Add a style dialog like the one I have linked to. I want to know the library that helps me to create this style.